# Why large HashMap causes long GC pauses

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I wrote a GC pause testing function, and found long STW time(>1.5s) with large HashMap(~ 3 million entries.) when invoking System.gc() explicitly.

I tried large ArrayList, and it showed same long GC pauses(litter shorter than Map).

Testing codes are as below:

```java
package tool.gc;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HashMapTest {
  Map<Integer, byte[]> map = new HashMap<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HashMapTest test = new HashMapTest();
    test.gcTestWithMap();
    System.out.println("prepare to gc, now:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    while (true) {
      System.gc();
      System.out.println("finish a round of gc");
      Thread.sleep(4000);
    }
  }

  public void gcTestWithMap() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000000; i++) {
      byte[] bytes = new byte[2000];
      for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        bytes[j] = 1;
      }
      map.put(i, bytes);
    }
  }
}
```

JVM startup parameters:

```sh
java -Xmx10g -Xms10g  
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDetails  
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails  -Xloggc:gc.log 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ParallelCMSThreads=8 
-cp test-1.0.0.jar tool.gc.HashMapTest
```

Some GC logs as below:

```
2019-07-08T10:27:35.386+0800: 438.306: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 2.1067575 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000317 seconds
2019-07-08T10:27:37.386+0800: 440.306: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006364 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000209 seconds
2019-07-08T10:27:38.298+0800: 441.218: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0036499 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000249 seconds
2019-07-08T10:27:41.143+0800: 444.063: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 1.7568843 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000237 seconds
2019-07-08T10:27:41.144+0800: 444.064: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006293 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000453 seconds
2019-07-08T10:27:42.033+0800: 444.953: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0039319 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000295 seconds
```

In my understanding, HashMap Object could be one of GC roots but not all the entries. My question is: what might be the root cause of the long STW.

Comment: That's 3m entries, you are maximizing the memory of your application. The more memory you consume each time you add data to hashmap the less responsive the UI. What's the purpose of 3m entries that's a lot of data?

Comment: @NJY404 My application maintains 3m entries of some metadata persisted in memory for comparison. I have workaround by putting the 3m data to redis, but I'd like to find the root cause for the pauses. Is it reasonable to consume 1.5 seconds to stop-the-world?

Comment: I suggest using the `AsyncTask` rather than running those in the UI Thread. Hope it helps

Comment: @NJY404 There *is* no UI thread, and this isn't an Android application at all.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, my bad. How about creating a new Thread instead.

Comment: “*In my understanding, HashMap Object could be one of GC roots but not all the entries.*” Your understanding is correct, but there's no relevance in that. The garbage collector still must traverse all these references, whether root or not. The simple answer is, don't invoke `System.gc()` manually.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good way how to test your application responsiveness. You should run it under a realistic workload number of times and observe the application behavior with monitoring tools and enabled GC logging. 
Then you can judge whether latency introduced by GC are acceptable or not.

With that done, you can try to improve your code and/or experiment with different JVM settings.
And probably upgrade the JDK version you use since it seems to be 8 or older.

PS: To get additional details in GC logs, you could also include *safepoint statistics* (see https://blog.jayan.kandathil.ca/gc_logging_in_java11.html).